# which is the best way to buffering UART RX incoming data?

Tags: c, buffer, uart

I am using a GSM modem attached to my microcontroller, to send/receive AT commands, also I am performing connection to a remote server using MQTT.

after some research I made my own UART AT command parser implementation to receive and send commands it is working almost fine all the time, but I would like a better quality code, I think the way I implementing it could be a little rough

I added a simulated "UART" on the code below to give a better understanding what I am doing, it is not working 100% fine because is a simulation

**My question is: how can I improve the code below? what are the best practices for receiving incoming data using UART and creating a own buffer?**

**code**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 static void at_wait_msg(char text);
 static char _rx_data[512];
 static uint16_t _rx_index = 0;

 enum messagetype
 {
     CommandReceived = 0,
     Buffering,
     ReceivingMQTT
 };
 messagetype type;

 int main()
 {
     char text[] = "\nAT\nOK\nAT\n0...readertesttagsample1000"; //example data getting from UART1
     //0...readertesttagsample1000(hex format for MQTT 30 18 00 09 72 65 61 64 65 72 74 73 74 74 61 67 73 61 6D 70 6C 65 31 30 30 30
     //pub:30
     //total len 24
     //topic len 9
     //data the remaining bytes
     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text) + 1; i++)
         at_wait_msg(text[i]); //to simulate getting data from UART1 byte per byte
     return 0;
 }

 static void at_wait_msg(char text)
 {
     if (text == 0x0A)
     {
         type =CommandReceived;
     }

     if (text != 0x0A && type == Buffering)
     {
         type = Buffering;
     }

     if (text == 0x30)
     {
         type = ReceivingMQTT;
     }

     switch (type)
     {
         case Buffering:
              _rx_data[_rx_index++] = text;
              break;

         case CommandReceived:
              printf(" buffer[%s]\r", _rx_data);
              memset(_rx_data, 0, _rx_index);   
              _rx_index = 0;
              type = Buffering;
              break;

         case ReceivingMQTT:
              printf(" buffer[%s]\r", _rx_data);
              memset(_rx_data, 0, _rx_index);   
              _rx_index = 0;
              type = Buffering;
              break;
     }  
 }
```

Comment: In `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text) + 1; i++)` I don't think you should be sending the string's `nul` terminator, but a newline. Aside: the loop was clumsy, better as `for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(text); i++)` although you should not send the `'\0'`. Also you have to rely on the compiler optimising the `strlen` in every loop.

Comment: I suggest putting the `\n` at the end, and not at the beginning of each **AT** message. New coders often do that with `stdout` output too. Sometimes you need `\n` at the start of a message, but almost always it should be at the end.

Comment: Sidenote: all names starting with underscore are reserved for the implementation at file level.

Comment: oh no guys, that **char text[]** is just to simulate AT command coming to the UART port, my real application is at_wait_msg and below. when buffering the incoming data

Comment: Another sidenote: always use a 'default' statment in conjuntion wirth switch.

Comment: Another sidenote: be aware of your coding style

Comment: @Mike well, that is the main reason I am posting here. I want to improve my coding style for a more reliable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement circular buffer 
    A circular buffer, circular queue, cyclic buffer or ring buffer is a data structure that uses a single, fixed-size buffer as if it were connected end-to-end. This structure lends itself easily to buffering data streams.

That was from Wikipedia.  How to implement it? You need a pointer or index which points to the queue head and another one to the tail. You can also can keep track of the length and head or tail of the queue. Then the head or tail goes out of the buffer it changes to the start of it